# How to Generate Unique ID in Java (Integer)?

Tags: java, uniqueidentifier, uid

How to generate unique ID that is integer in java that not guess next number?

Comment: Perhaps you should be a little more precise about the context of your needs.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

How unique does it need to be?

If it's only unique within a process, then you can use an [`AtomicInteger`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) and call [`incrementAndGet()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet%28%29) each time you need a new value.

Comment: Even better to prime AtomicInteger with Integer.MIN_VALUE. This helps in debugging and gives you more numbers to play with.

Comment: also you need to think about overflow. smth like `if (curInt == Integer.MAX_INT)` reset atomicInteger

Answer (score 9):

```
int uniqueId = 0;

int getUniqueId()
{
    return uniqueId++;
}
```

Add `synchronized` if you want it to be thread safe.

Comment: Might want to add an exception for when it the integers get too high and roll over.  Also might want to start uniqueId at Integer.MinInt() (Method is called something like that).

Comment: This will work only when the process runs forever without stopping. For restarted apps, it will start from 0 each time.

Comment: Well, one might think about using a Long instead of Integer in the first place.

Answer (score 8):

```
 import java.util.UUID;

 public class IdGenerator {
    public static int generateUniqueId() {      
        UUID idOne = UUID.randomUUID();
        String str=""+idOne;        
        int uid=str.hashCode();
        String filterStr=""+uid;
        str=filterStr.replaceAll("-", "");
        return Integer.parseInt(str);
    }

    // XXX: replace with java.util.UUID

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(generateUniqueId());
            //generateUniqueId();
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: -1. While a UUID will certainly provide a unique value, there's no guarantee that this uniqueness guarantee persists when you take its hashcode. You may as will pick a random number between Integer.MIN_VALUE and Integer.MAX_VALUE and hope for the best.

Comment: Not so. UUID.randomUUID() uses a cryptographically strong random number generator, so that should be better than using a weaker pseudorandom number generator.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy if you are somewhat constrained.

If you have one thread, you just use uniqueID++;  Be sure to store the current uniqueID when you exit.

If you have multiple threads, a common synchronized generateUniqueID method works (Implemented the same as above).

The problem is when you have many CPUs--either in a cluster or some distributed setup like a peer-to-peer game.

In that case, you can generally combine two parts to form a single number.  For instance, each process that generates a unique ID can have it's own 2-byte ID number assigned and then combine it with a uniqueID++.  Something like:

```
return (myID << 16) & uniqueID++
```

It can be tricky distributing the "myID" portion, but there are some ways.  You can just grab one out of a centralized database, request a unique ID from a centralized server, ...

If you had a Long instead of an Int, one of the common tricks is to take the device id (UUID) of ETH0, that's guaranteed to be unique to a server--then just add on a serial number.

Answer (score 2):

If you really meant integer rather than int:

```
Integer id = new Integer(42); // will not == any other Integer
```

If you want something visible outside a JVM to other processes or to the user, persistent, or a host of other considerations, then there are other approaches, but without context you are probably better off using using the built-in uniqueness of object identity within your system.

Answer (score 1):

Just generate ID and check whether it is already present or not in your list of generated IDs.

Answer (score 1):

[UUID class](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)

Comment: That doesn't return an integer. Format is hexstring, like `20e8f3d6-3f8d-475b-8c19-9619a78bbdc8`.

Comment: @BalusC: This is merely the String output you're talking about.  Internally a UUID is a 128-bit value and hence could be interpreted as an integer (albeit BigInteger).

Comment: Still, it doesn't fit in an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need it to be;

- unique between two JVMs running at
  the same time.
- unique even if the JVM
  is restarted.
- thread-safe.
- support null? if not, use int or long.

Comment: Bill K. gave a solution for the first case, i.e. what can be done if want the id to be unique between 2 JVMs. What's the right approach to make sure that the id is unique even after JVM restarts?

Comment: Oh, requesting a uniqueId from one of a centralized databases will work after restarts too.

Answer (score 0):

if only int is required then AtomicInteger can make it possible.

if String is needed then the below code should work by mixing timeStamp and
AtomicLong.

```
AtomicLong idCounter =  new AtomicLong(100);
long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
long nextLong = idCounter.incrementAndGet();
String randomId = String.valueOf(timestamp)+String.valueOf(nextLong);
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a class called employee with these attributes:

```
public class Employee {
    
    private final String name;
    private int id;
    private static int nextID = 1;
    
    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name= name;
        id = nextID++;
    }
}
```

Easy peasy

Answer (score -1):

Unique at any time:

```
int uniqueId = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() & 0xfffffff);
```

Comment: Referring to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2979239/344480), `System.currentTimeMillis()` does not return unique values.