# measuring execution time in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Measure execution time for a Java method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382954/measure-execution-time-for-a-java-method)

I would like to test my app, I know there's a certain method in java that returns the execution time but I couldn't find it. Any hints?

Comment: Sorry yotamoo - what do you mean by java runtime?  The JRE version?  java.lang.runtime?

Comment: He might me asking for Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

Comment: Try this AOP-based mechanism: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382954/measure-execution-time-for-a-java-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
long startTime = new Date().getTime();
doSomething();
long endTime = new Date().getTime();
System.out.println("elapsed milliseconds: " + (endTime - startTime));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
//...
long entTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long spentTime = endTime - startTime;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
//long start = System.nanoTime();
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
//long end = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println("time diff = " + (end - start) + " ms");
```

you can use `nanoTime()` instead of `currentTimeMillis()` for extra accuracy more discussion about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351565/system-currenttimemillis-vs-system-nanotime/351571#351571)

Answer (score 0):

```
long start, end, total;

start = System.currentTimeMillis();
// do stuff   
end = System.currentTimeMillis();

total = end - start;
```

total will contain the time to run through the main section of your code in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Java expert but I don't think there is such function. What can you do is to check the system time before and after the bits of code you with to test.[& This is one useful implementation.](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do;jsessionid=6DF6DDE32B439D4A712DA9D33E33BAB8?Id=85)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a current snapshot of the system time with `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

If you're looking to generate more complicated performance statistics than just timing a single block of code, I'd take a look at the [perf4j library](http://perf4j.codehaus.org/index.html).  It provides tools for logging performance stats and generating aggregated statistics like mean, min and max times.