# Is this Java cache threadsafe and optimal?

Tags: java, concurrency

Can this Java cache be safer or faster?

```
public class Cache {
    private long lastupdateTime = 0L;
    private String cachedData = null;
    public String getData() {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (now - lastupdateTime < 30000) {
            return cachedData;
        }
        else {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (now - lastupdateTime < 30000) {
                    return cachedData;
                }
                else {
                    lastupdateTime = now;
                    cachedData = getDataFromDatabase();
                    return cachedData;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private String getDataFromDatabase() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Why the double check *if (now - lastupdateTime < 30000)*  ?

Comment: @Fernando It appears to be a form of double checked locking.  Although I am not sure it is implemented properly, as you would want to use the `volatile` keyword to avoid register caching.  Further, you would need to be working in Java5+ (which everyone should be by now...)

Comment: @nicholas Yep, it doesn't seems right i guess... *synchronized(this)*? And the *lastupdateTime* is never updated.

Comment: @Fernando - OP is assuming `getDataFromDatabase` will update `lastupdateTime` so if you are locked out on `synchronized` another thread may have updated.

Comment: Which will be very bad. I would create a daemon thread (using a timer maybe) that synchs on the cached data, but i'm not sure if that's the best way.

Comment: Forgot to update lastupdatetime. I just added that

Comment: Yeah, but this second *if* doesn't make sense... *now* doesn't change between these 2 *if's*.

Comment: Added explicit write to cachedData too

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Even ignoring the fact that you haven't made `lastupdateTime` or `cachedData` volatile,

```
                lastupdateTime = now;
                cachedData = getDataFromDatabase();
```

is out of order.

If `getDataFromDatabase` fails with an exception, you will have already updated `lastupdateTime` , so will keep returning stale data for 30s, possibly returning `null` if `getDataFromDatabase` fails on the first attempt.

You would lose nothing by initializing `lastUpdateTime` to `Long.MIN_VALUE`, and would work more reliably on systems whose clocks have been set backwards.

`System.getCurrentTimeMillis` can go [backwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978598/will-sytem-currenttimemillis-always-return-a-value-previous-calls) which is unlikely to affect a 30s cache, but for this use case there's really no reason not to use `System.nanoTime()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea - on the principle that `synchronized` is an archaic and inefficient mechanism.

Here I use an `AtomicReference<Phaser>` to indicate the cache is being updated. The `Phaser` can be used to await completion of the update.

```
public class Test {

  public static class Cache {
    // Cache timeout.
    private static final long Timeout = 10000;
    // Last time we updated.
    private volatile long lastupdateTime = 0L;
    // The cached data.
    private volatile String cachedData = null;
    // Cache is in the progress of updating.
    private AtomicReference<Phaser> updating = new AtomicReference<>();
    // The next Phaser to use - avoids unnecessary Phaser creation.
    private Phaser nextPhaser = new Phaser(1);

    public String getData() {
      // Do this just once.
      long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
      // Watch for expiry.
      if (now - lastupdateTime > Timeout) {
        // Make sure only one thread updates.
        if (updating.compareAndSet(null, nextPhaser)) {
          // We are the unique thread that gets to do the updating.
          System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - Get ...");
          // Get my new cache data.
          cachedData = getDataFromDatabase();
          lastupdateTime = now;
          // Make the Phaser to use next time - avoids unnecessary creations.
          nextPhaser = new Phaser(1);
          // Get the queue and clear it - there cannot be any new joiners after this.
          Phaser queue = updating.getAndSet(null);
          // Inform everyone who is waiting that they can go.
          queue.arriveAndDeregister();
        } else {
          // Wait in the queue.
          Phaser queue = updating.get();
          if (queue != null) {
            // Wait for it.
            queue.register();
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - Waiting ...");
            queue.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - Back");
          }
        }
      }
      // Let them have the correct data.
      return cachedData;
    }

    private String getDataFromDatabase() {
      try {
        // Deliberately wait for a bit.
        Thread.sleep(5000);
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        // Ignore.
      }
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - Hello");
      return "Hello";
    }
  }

  public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    // Start time.
    final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // Make a Cache.
    final Cache c = new Cache();
    // Make some threads.
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < 60000) {
            c.getData();
            try {
              Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
              // Ignore.
            }
          }
        }
      });
      t.setName("Thread - " + i);
      t.start();
      // Stagger the threads.
      Thread.sleep(300);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    new Test().test();
  }
}
```

Please note that this is the first time I have used a `Phaser` - I hope I have it right.

Note that this algorithm may break down if the timeout is longer than the time it takes to get the data from the database.

Comment: `// Watch for expiry.
 if (now - lastupdateTime > 30000) ` , you are accessing to shared mutable state without any form of synchronization

Comment: @tarrsalah - Good call - should be `volatile`.

Answer (score 0):

You have your `Cash` class with two **shared** **mutable** state `lastupdateTime` and `cachedData`, `getData()` can be invoked conurrenctly by two different threads, it use a local variable `now` that can be visible to other threads (alocated in the `stack`)

#### What's wrong ?

- First  `if (now - lastupdateTime < 30000) { return cachedData;}`, Other thread can see `stale` data on `lastupdateTime` and `cachedData` (you are accessing to a thared mutable state without **synchronization** guarantee)
- `now` variable form such a **invariant** with `lastupdateTime`, so `now - lastupdateTime` should be executed in an `Atomic Block`

#### What can I do ?

Just make `method` `synchronized`, and make your class totally **thread-safe**

```
public class Cache {
    private long lastupdateTime = 0L;
    private String cachedData = null;
    public synchronized String getData() {
           long now = System.currentTimeMillis()
           if (nano - lastupdateTime < 30000) {
                return cachedData;
           }
           else {
               lastupdateTime = now;
               cachedData = getDataFromDatabase();
               return cachedData;
           }                
    }
    private String getDataFromDatabase() { ... }
}
```