# How to generate a unique Id for each object of a class?

Tags: java

Will `java.util.UUID` work for classes in Java? That is to say i have a class that requires a unique id such that each time i construct an object of that class inside the main method, it will have a unique ID number.

the constructor might look something like this:

```
class flight{
        private UUID id;

        public void flight(){
           id = UUID.randomUUID();
        }
}
```

and the main method call might look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    flight[] allflights = new flight[100];
    flight tempFlight;

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        tempFlight = new flight()
        allflights[i] = tempFlight;
    }
```

Will this generate a unique ID for all the flights inside the flight array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate unique ID in java (Integer)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178992/how-to-generate-unique-id-in-java-integer)

Comment: Not sure if you got a chance to look at the first response of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325443/generate-uuid-in-java which talks about when a collision could happen!

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Can you not use an AtomicInteger as a counter?

Comment: Take a look at [Flyweight design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern). Looks like this is what you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is what UUIDs are for. You'll get a new random UUID every time you call randomUUID() ; a UUID is a 128bit value.

So theoretically you could get collisions when using random UUIDs, but as it says that a cryptographically strong random generator is used i don't think you need to bother with that possibility.

Answer (score 3):

As the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID%28%29) explains, this would indeed generate a unique id for each object:

> Static factory to retrieve a type 4 (pseudo randomly generated) `UUID`.
>   The `UUID` is generated using a cryptographically strong pseudo random
>   number generator.

As [Vidkor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/240078/vikdor) explains in a comment, [there is a chance of collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325443/generate-uuid-in-java) though.

Comment: Is it really true that it generates unique ids? I thought that UUIDs are *practically* unique rather than *guaranteed*. So it COULD be possible that two objects share the same id. All depends on the used algorithm, since it is a very long random generated number (Java it is 128bit I think). But its right to say: "Maybe, its never happen" :)

Comment: Yes, I have already incorporated Vidkors comment, which links to a question dealing with this issue.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to your question is in your question.

Run that code printing the UUIDs and you'll find out, what's so hard about adding `System.out.println`?

public static void main(String[] args){
    flight[] allflights = new flight[100];
    flight tempFlight;

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
    tempFlight = new flight()
    allflights[i] = tempFlight;
    System.out.println(tempFlight.getId());
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment, and even then, it is not a helpful one. Just observing a few UUIDs manually doesn't verify that all of them will be unique.

Comment: So the actual question is wether **Universally unique identifiers** are unique?

Comment: No, the question is whether UUIDs generated like in the OPs code are unique. It may be a very simple question, but that doesn't mean one can't simply answer it.

Comment: I sincerely don't understand you.  You're asking if unique ids are uniques? :/

Comment: As has been pointed out in comments by Vidkor and christian.vogel, UUIDs are in fact not guaranteed to be unique. However, the main reason that I criticized your answer is that it is unfriendly and unhelpful to the OP. It is not a good answer.