# How to use auto increment for an object type in android?

Tags: java, android

Okay, I am saving files in a json file which which unlike a db that has an auto-increment function.

Say I have this object.

```
public book() {
id = ?????
Title = mTitle;
}
```

How can you make the id to give you an unique int number? is that possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178992/how-to-generate-unique-id-in-java-integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a static variable in the class and increment it.

```
class Book {

 private static int increment = 0;
 public Book() {
   id = ++increment;
   Title = mTitle;
 }

}
```

Please follow some naming conventions. Class names should start with uppercase.

Comment: Unless you have a need to know the next id outside the class, increment should be private.

Comment: suppose the app is restarted the values will be initialized to zero again right?

Comment: suppose the app is restarted then even the objects he created with unique ids will not exist . If the requirement is such then he needs to persist the last id somewhere . My answer was in context till app is up in the JVM , not for consecutive running of the app.

Answer (score 2):

You have several solutions.

**1** Put to your ID `System.currentTimeMillis()` or even `System.nonoTime()`. This will almost guarantee uniqueness and the numbers will be consequent.

**2** Create static counter that just counts the objects:

example:

```
public class Book {
   private static int count = 0;
   private int id;

   public Book() {
       id = ++count;
   }
}
```

This approach will guarantee the uniqueness of IDs within the same instance of your application.

**3** You can also use class `UUID` that generates truly unique string IDs.

Answer (score 1):

If you auto-generate your getters/setters, be sure to mark setId() as protected and remove the argument passed in.

```
public protected void setId() {}
```